# Radiogroup does not have a value

Tags: extjs

I have a problem with radiogroups in ExtJS 6.2.1.

The user is editing two different records from the same store in two forms located next to each other.

Radio group values are only set on the form where the value has been changed last. The other value is empty.

I have reproduced this in a small fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23t8

Is this an ExtJS bug and if so, how to fix?

Comment: You use same name to create different groups which is opposite what you want to achieve.If you want to create two different groups try to name accordingly like x1 and x2. I guess this will fix your problem

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz This is impossible because the name has to be the same to correctly load a record instance into the form (all instances have the same field with name "x").